# Image Upload ending prematurely nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, stream, socket.io

Using node.js, I decided it was time to work with file uploads. Looking at my options, I felt that uploading with socketio was the best bet for me. This of course brought my list of modules down with not being able to use multer or other ways that require you to load another http request. I finally settled with **socket.io-stream** and everything was working great until I tried uploading bigger files (200 KB or bigger) which is not that great being that the average size of stuff that will be uploaded is anything from 50 KB to 700 KB with the max of 1MB. It seems to me that the upload is ending prematurely without any clue on why. Although I feel like the problem is server side, here is both the client and server.

Client:

```
var file = $("#map").prop('files')[0];
        var stream = ss.createStream();
        ss(m).emit('file', stream, {name: file.name});
```

Server:

```
   ss(socket).on('file', function(stream, data) {
            var filename = path.basename(data.name);
            var way = '/images/maps/uploaded/';
            stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('public'+way+filename));
            stream.on('end', function() {
                socket.emit('fileDone', "<img src='" + way + filename + "' height='200px;' width='400px'/>");
            });
        });
```

As you can probably tell the main function will be to upload images. The client side works so I'm not worried about that. On the server side, I will get the file and then save it in the uploaded directory. The stream.on is for a callback to show the uploaded image after it is done.

When uploading most "big files" (over 200KB) it only partially works like the picture below and ones that tend to be bigger than 700KB will show a size 0 after uploading.

[image: Example of bad upload]

Comment: FWIW you should listen for the `finish` event on the `Writable` stream instead of `end` on the `Readable` stream. The reason being that `finish` indicates that all data has been flushed to the file system. When `end` is emitted, there could still be some data buffered in memory in the `Writable` stream.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also tried finish instead of end and got the same problem. If you look at the code above, I used end on the writable stream but I will keep messing with it to figure it out.

Comment: The `end` is on the `Readable` stream in your code. What I suggested was something like: `stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('public'+way+filename)).on('finish', function() { socket.emit(...) });` That listens for `finish` on the file `Writable` stream. `Readable` streams do not emit `finish`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it still did not work. I even tried to remove that whole part where it listens for the finish so that the code ends with the stream.pipe

Comment: What I did is switch from using socket.io-stream to socketio-file-upload and my problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a perfect solution to the problem but more of a work around. Using socket.io-steam, I had this problem but switching to socketio-file-upload fixed my problem. Still have no idea on why it did not work the first way.